# Disable SSL on one domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, domain

I have a server with ISPconfig and nginx, where there are two domains set up.
I have an SSL cert on one domain, and I have SSL disabled on the other one, however domain2 can still be accessed by https redirecting it to domain1.

Is it possible to make https unaccessible for domain2?

Comment: Does the server only have a single IP address? What do you want to happen when someone tries to access domain2 using https?

Comment: Yes it has only one IP. I was expecting no connection whatsoever on domain2 with https or atleast an error

Comment: Since they share an IP, you're connecting to the same IP and the same port, right? So why would you expect no connection?

Comment: One possibility is to add some logic on the HTTPS frontend to check the domain and return an "error" page if domain2 is accessed.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make https unaccessible for domain2?

If they're on the same IP address? **No**.

`https://` isn't magic. All it means is "Connect to the target host (IP address) on port 443, and initiate a SSL handshake before doing the HTTP stuff."
If you have one IP address and want to serve https requests you have to listen on that IP address, port 443, and there's no way for the server to know what *name* the user typed into their URL bar until after the connection has been made.